# Excel Power Query Can't Access Postgresql Views

Tags: excel, postgresql, powerquery

I'm setting up Excel Office 365 to access one of our PostgreSQL (9.6) databases via Power Query.  Specifically, I'm trying to connect to a View I wrote to return a particular data set.

We're using an ODBC DSN for the connection, using the Postgres Unicode ODBC driver.

I have a weird problem where on my PC this all works fine.  But, on a co-workers laptop, it fails.  I can connect to a real table on his, but not to a view.  The error message is extremely terse.  It simply says Error=Table.  I'm not sure what that means, except perhaps it's telling me that it can only connect to tables?  But if so, why only on that machine?

This is the actual error I get:

> DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] Error while executing the query
>   Details:
>       DataSourceKind=Odbc
>       DataSourcePath=dsn=uranus_emd
>       OdbcErrors=Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by installing an actual .NET connector on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I also see this problem using VBScript to access a postgres VIEW through an ODBC driver.

I had to work around it by expandingt the details of the query to use only TABLES and effectively recreate the VIEW in SQL

Answer (score -2):

Get node.js http://microsoft.com/ekkarat.w@gmail.com/
import sequence from '@start/plugin-sequence'
import find from '@start/plugin-find'
import read from '@start/plugin-read'
import babel from '@start/plugin-lib-babel'
import write from '@start/plugin-write'

const babelConfig = {
  // …
  babelrc: false,
  sourceMap: true,
}

export const task = () =>
  sequence(
    find('src/**/*.js'),
    read,
    babel(babelConfig),
    write('build/')
  )